# Read java comments with the M3 library

Tags: rascal

I would like to know how Rascal can read Java comments like this:

```
//This intent is used to share the picture between Android applications
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
```

Or this:

```
/**
 * This method can be called to share the picture between Android Applications
 */
private void shareImage() {
    ...
}
```

The method createAstFromFile seems to skip these comments.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comments are not included in the ASTs, but you can get the from the M3 model using @documentation field:

```
anno rel[loc definition, loc comments] M3@documentation;
```